# How do I strip a file extension from a string in C?

Tags: c, string, replace, split

How do I strip a file extension from a string in C?

For example,

If I have the filenames with the file extensions

> hello.txt
>
> hello.c
>
> hello.java

should all result in just the filename without the extension as

> hello

the length of the file extension shouldn't matter.

the function should also be portable and **not** system dependent.

I know how to get the file extension using `strchr` or `strrchr`. I've done this in Bash and in Python, but I've never had to do this in C.

*Note: This is for a personal exercise to help strengthen my understanding of the C programming language.*

Comment: if you're going to down-vote this post, the least you can do is say why. i thought this site was supposed to advocate learning through asking legitimate targeted questions. according to the help-center, i am allowed to ask a question that is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". according to the questions i should avoid asking states "if your motivation is “I would like others to explain _ to me”, then you are probably OK.". if you feel the question is inappropriately worded, then edit it so that it's better suited to an on-topic question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know that there is a best way, but here is one way. Presumably you don't want to strip the name from dot files. Also, you probably only want to remove the characters from the last dot to the end of the string. Note that in the code below, the input string is modified, so the filename can't be a string literal, but must be a null-terminated character array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strip_ext(char *);

int main(void)
{
    char filename1[] = "myfile.txt";
    char filename2[] = ".emacs";
    char filename3[] = "anotherfile.";
    char filename4[] = "nodot";
    char filename5[] = "";
    char filename6[] = "dot.dot.dot";

    strip_ext(filename1);
    strip_ext(filename2);
    strip_ext(filename3);
    strip_ext(filename4);
    strip_ext(filename5);
    strip_ext(filename6);

    printf("file1: %s\n", filename1);
    printf("file2: %s\n", filename2);
    printf("file3: %s\n", filename3);
    printf("file4: %s\n", filename4);
    printf("file5: %s\n", filename5);
    printf("file6: %s\n", filename6);

    return 0;
}

void strip_ext(char *fname)
{
    char *end = fname + strlen(fname);

    while (end > fname && *end != '.') {
        --end;
    }

    if (end > fname) {
        *end = '\0';
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
file1: myfile
file2: .emacs
file3: anotherfile
file4: nodot
file5: 
file6: dot.dot
```

### Update

[@David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163677/whats-the-best-way-to-strip-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-c/43163740?noredirect=1#comment73403542_43163740) has pointed out that more complex filepaths may complicate matters. Below is a modification to the `strip_ext()` function that stops looking for a dot when either a forward or back slash is encountered, in which case the filename string remains unchanged:

```
void strip_ext(char *fname)
{
    char *end = fname + strlen(fname);

    while (end > fname && *end != '.' && *end != '\\' && *end != '/') {
        --end;
    }
    if ((end > fname && *end == '.') &&
        (*(end - 1) != '\\' && *(end - 1) != '/')) {
        *end = '\0';
    }  
}
```

Running this function with the same test strings, and the additional test strings:

```
char filename7[] = "/my.dir/myfile";
char filename8[] = "/dir/.filename";
```

generates this output:

```
file1: myfile
file2: .emacs
file3: anotherfile
file4: nodot
file5: 
file6: dot.dot
file7: /my.dir/myfile
file8: /dir/.filename
```

Comment: why does `end > fname` work as a conditional expression? aren't they just addresses to the first character of the string?

Comment: `end` and `fname` are pointers to `char`, which point to the same array object. `end` starts at the `\0`, and `fname` of course points to the first character of the filename. [If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object... pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p5).

Comment: so, if i understand correctly, you tell `end` to point past the last element in the array. then compare that to `fname`, which yields true. once the objects are equal, it yields false, essentially "stripping" anything past the `'.'` character and then replace the `'.'` with the null character.

Comment: Well, the `end` pointer starts by pointing to the `\0` terminator, i.e., the _last_ element of the array. But otherwise, yes. If the loop terminates when `end == fname`, note that no `\0` is placed, so the names of dotfiles are not converted to empty strings.

Comment: i have to say, that's incredibly clever and completely nuanced. lol, C, you got me again. so, it seems that no matter what i do, i must replace the `'.'` character with a null character, which just terminates the string there leaving the rest in memory. very cool, either way. thank you for you're awe inspiring answer.

Comment: I like the start, but what happens with `/my.dir/myfile`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin-- interesting point; I didn't consider entire filepaths. I suppose the loop could terminate with a back or forwards slash.

Comment: That more like it. Always protect against the user doing something dumb.

Comment: That's a good answer but it won't work with something like `/dir/.filename` because you're not checking for preceding separators in your if condition.

`if (end > fname && *end == '.' && *(end-1) != '/' && *(end-1) != '\\')` should hopefully cover all cases.

Comment: @idk -- good catch; updated. There are still pathological cases that may not be handled correctly. `file..txt` would be stripped to `file.`, which may or may not be the desired result, and `..txt` would be stripped to `.`, which is almost certainly not the desired result. I don't see any point in trying to find all of the edge cases for an answer like this. Yet the case you found is not an edge case, but an important and common case that I should have caught the first time around. Thanks for the heads-up ;)

Answer (score 1):

There could be many ways of doing it. One way could be replace the first dot with a null character (`\0`).

```
char [] filename = "Hello.java";

for(int i=0;i<strlen(filename);i++) {
   if(filename[i] == '.') {
       filename[i]='\0';
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: To prevent calling `strlen` repeatedly to test for loop exit condition, better to do `int len = (int)strlen (filename); for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {...}`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, absolutely. However my intention here was to show the OP a working answer, not necessarily a performance oriented full-fledged solution. But I always appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best way, but a possible solution is putting a NULL terminator in the place of the dot, which can be achieved by the following code.

```
char *filename_dot = strchr(filename, '.');
int offset = filename_dot - filename;
filename[offset] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const char * s_name // pointing to ex "myString.ext"

char * s_atext = strstr(s_name, ".ext");
if (s_atext != NULL) {
    /* Extract the filename without extension in case only */
    size_t name_only_size = s_atext - s_name;
    char * s_name_only = strndup(s_name, name_only_size); 
    // use your s_name_only
    printf("FileName w/o ext: %s\n", s_name_only);
    if (s_name_only) free(s_name_only);
}
```

Comment: `if (s_name_only) free(s_name_only);` is pointless as `s_name_only` would have made the program segfault in `printf` if it were null.